# Java Restful - get methods return Null

Tags: java, rest

Like the title says the two methods public String getUsername() and public String getPassword() that query my database both return null values when called even though I got entries in my database

This is how I call the two methods

```
if(user!=null && user.getUsername().equals(userId) && user.getPassword().equals(password))
```

And these are the bodies

```
 public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  I would suggest that the problem is not with the `getter` methods

Comment: The thing is that I'm not doing anything really. I created a database with some entries in it. I then create RestFul Services from a database, which generated the Users class which has the two methods in it. I would suppose that when you call the methods you get the list of entries sorted by the said attribute. I'm wrong in thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to keep in mind following areas,
1. Data base connection
2. Repository layer functionality (Data retrieve layer from database)
3. Attributes of the User entity

Important : Please double check whether you have add proper Annotation in each place.
eg : 
-Controller layer @Controller/ @RestController/ @RequestMapping/
-Service layer @Service/ @Autowired
-Repository layer @Repository
-Entity classes @Entity/ @Column etc.